# Why multiple transactions with one session are not being committed?

Tags: hibernate, transactions

I'm trying to submit multiple transactions in one session using hibernate. But for some reason only the first one is being submitted to the database:

```
private final DaoFactory df = new DaoFactory();
df.beginConnectionScope();

Object1Dao o1d = df.createDao(Object1Dao.class);

try{
    df.beginTransaction();
    //update object1
    df.endTransaction();
    if (something){
        df.beginTransaction();
        Object2Dao o2d = df.createDao(Object2Dao.class);
        //update object2
        df.endTransaction();
    } else if (orderItem.isClosed()){
        df.beginTransaction();
        Object2Dao o2d = df.createDao(Object2Dao.class);
        //update object 2
        df.endTransaction();
    }
    success = true;
} catch (Exception ex){
    df.rollback();
} finally {         
    df.endConnectionScope();
}
```

My DaoFactory.beginTransaction:

```
public void beginTransaction(){
    if (tx == null || !tx.isActive()) {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
    }
}
```

My DaoFactory.endTransaction:

```
public void endTransaction(){
    tx.commit();
    tx = null;
}
```

The session is controlled by the DaoFactory and is only realeased when DaoFactory.endConnectionScope is called.

What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: Try updating objects in one single transaction, to see if it helps.

Comment: @DarshanLila If I run the transactions in this order it doesn't work. But if I update the object2 first it does work. I guess the reason is that object2 contains a set of object1. Can anyone explain me why?

Comment: It depends on your business logic, how you maintain dependencies, what is your transaction policies etc..